# Python Selenium "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, autofill

I am trying to use Selenium to sign up an email account automatically whenever I need to.  It's just a fun learning project for me.  For the life of me I don't understand why it can't find the element.  This code works fine on the sign-in page but not the sign-up page.  I have tried all different Selenium commands and even tried using the ID and class name.  Either is says it can't locate the element or that it is not reachable by keyboard.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time


options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')


driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en")
time.sleep(10)
username_input = driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("testusername")
```

Also here is the HTML code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2xRV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username field is in **iframe**, you need to switch to **iframe** to make this work.
Below is the code that works fine :

```
driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Registration form'][class='top']"))
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("some string")
```

1. read more about iframe [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)
2. learn more about how to switch to iframe/frame/framset using Python
   selenium Bindings [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

**Update :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Registration form'][class='top']"))
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("some string")
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Registration form'][class='bottom']"))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "submitBtn"))).click()
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you, I'm reading the links you provided as well.  Was trying to figure this out the past few hours.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Another question.  For the "sign up" buttom it's also in an iframe.  Here is the code: https://i.imgur.com/FMnJQfN.png  The code I did to switch to the iframe should work, it's the same you gave but it's "unable to locate element" driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Registration form'][class='bottom']"))
create_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-submit").actions.click("btn btn-submit")

Comment: @Sims : no you would need to switch to default content first using `driver.switch_to.default_content()` and then you can switch to new iframe `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Registration form'][class='bottom']"))`

Comment: Before I did the above code I did driver.switch_to.default_content() So it should be working but it's not.

Comment: @Sims : Are you referring to `create account button` ?

Comment: @Sims : If it is `create account button` the I have updated the code to scroll down and then click on create account button'. hope that helps

Comment: Thank you!  I will test it and go over it tomorrow.  Because I don't understand the script that you selected to execute.  I don't recall seeing that script.  Clearly I need to brush up on HTML haha.

Comment: Could you maybe explain this line of code? "driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")"  It's just a javascript command to scroll to the end of the page?  I just don't understand why it's needed.

Comment: @Sims : yes it is for scroll till end of the page. and it is needed cause when you click on create Account button you would have to manually scroll down right ? So without scrolling it is not in Selenium viewPort, so selenium will say either `ElemenetNotInteractable` or `TimeOutException` in case of explicit wait. Hope that clarify your doubts. Feel free to ask me anything or create any ticket for any info. Don't forget to tag Selenium.

Comment: Thank you!  There is no way to direct message on here?  I did actually have one other question.  What is the difference between WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5) and time.sleep(5) when I try to use WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5) it can't locate the element but it works when I do time.sleep(5).  I couldn't get an explanation on the library for selenium.

Comment: @Sims : No direct way :). `WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5)` and `time.sleep(5)` both falls under explicit wait. The worst case of explicit wait is `time.sleep(5)` that will stop the show for exactly 5 seconds. On the other hand WebdriverWait will try to find the element based on condition given and trying time is 500 ms (.5 sec) if found you could save 4.5 secs or 4 sec, 3.5 sec and so on.. if not found you will get `TimeOutException` read more here [link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've seen enough code to diagnose, but I think the way you are defining `username_input` seems problematic. `driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("testusername")` doesn't actually return anything so it seems like you are setting `username_input = null`.